# Automated testing of thread synchronization

Tags: automated-testing, threading

My program has two threads:

- Thread A scans the filesystem for files matching certain criteria, and adds them to an internal catalog.
- Thread B scans the internal catalog for entries matching certain other criteria, and deletes them from both the catalog and the filesystem.

I've got locking that *should* ensure the program does the correct thing if both threads decide to operate on the same item at the same time, rather than, for example, creating a "ghost" catalog entry that refers to a deleted file.  How can I verify this in an automated way?

The "correct thing" here is either "thread A notices the file, notices it's in the catalog, and skips it, then thread B notices the catalog entry, deletes the file and catalog entry, and continues" or "thread A notices the file, then thread B notices the catalog entry and deletes the file and catalog entry, then thread A notices the file has been deleted and skips it".  Ideally a test would verify that both correct interleavings of operations are possible, and that no incorrect interleavings are possible.

Comment: What programming language are you using? Different languages provide different APIs to check and modify the state of a thread. In some cases you can also be notified when the thread reach a specific state (e.g. it's waiting for IO or for a lock). So, depending on the language, the strategy can change.

Comment: @DavideVisentin, I'm using wxWidgets, which is more or less a wrapper around pthreads (so, somewhere between C and C++ for the language).